# EWS: How to get the appointment info of a resource (room) which was added to a meeting?

Tags: vb.net, exchangewebservices

After adding a new meeting, I always load the ConflictingMeetingCount property, to make doubly sure the meeting is set ok (ie. concurrency check), for example:

```
Dim oAppt As New Appointment(exchangeService)
' ..set properties..
oAppt.Save(SendInvitationsMode.SendOnlyToAll)
oAppt.Load(New PropertySet(AppointmentSchema.ConflictingMeetingCount))
If oAppt.ConflictingMeetingCount > 0 Then
  ' Whole lotta meetin goin on
End If
```

I'd like to do the same thing for attendees and room resources, but have no idea how to find the *related appointment* of, for example a room added to the meeting. For example (continuing from the above):

```
oAppt.Resources.Add("meetingroom1@mahcompany.com")
oAppt.Update(SendInvitationsOrCancellationsMode.SendOnlyToChanged)
Dim oResourceAppt = ** get the appt object for this resource **
If oResourceAppt.ConflictingMeetingCount > 0 Then
  ' This won't do at all
End If
```

Now, assuming another user slipped in an appt a moment before this code executed, we now have a conflicting appt there. So I'd like to obtain the Appointment object *related to that resource I just added*, so I can check. ie. Is this possible?

It's not enough just to to a FindAppointments on the time slot for that resource, because that will just return 2 appt objects but no way (afaik) to know which one belongs to this specific meeting.

Any ideas?